# AspNet Core 5.0 and register custom NLog LayoutRenderer

Tags: c#, nlog, asp.net-core-5.0

I use NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.10.0 in my ASP Net Core 5.0 application. And I created a simple custom ResultLayoutRenderer (shortened for simplicity):

```
[LayoutRenderer("result-payload")]
public class ResultLayoutRenderer : AspNetLayoutRendererBase
{
    protected override void DoAppend(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        var httpRequest = HttpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request;
        var result = httpRequest.Headers["Result"];
        builder.Append(result);
    }
}
```

My NLog config is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">

    <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    </extensions>
    
    <targets>
        <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
        <target name="database" xsi:type="Database"
            dbProvider="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection, Npgsql"
            dbHost="${configsetting:name=NlogConnection.DbHost}"
            dbDatabase="${configsetting:name=NlogConnection.Database}"
            dbUserName="${configsetting:name=NlogConnection.User}"
            dbPassword="${configsetting:name=NlogConnection.Password}"">
            
            <commandText>
                INSERT INTO logs (Application, Logged, Level, Message, Logger, Result) 
                VALUES (@Application, @Logged, @Level, @Message, @Logger, @Result);
            </commandText>
            
            <parameter name="@application" layout="AspNetCoreNlog" />
            <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date}" />
            <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
            <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
            <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />

            <parameter name="@result" layout="${result-payload}" />
            
        </target>
    </targets>
</nlog>
```

I register the `ResultLayoutRenderer` in the `Programm.cs`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config")
        .Setup()
        .SetupExtensions(s => s.RegisterLayoutRenderer<InputDataLayout>("result-payload"))
        .GetCurrentClassLogger();
        ..............
}
```

But the layout doesn't work. The NLog internal log file contains the following information:

```
Error Error parsing layout input-payload will be ignored. Exception: System.ArgumentException: LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'input-payload'
   at NLog.Config.Factory`2.CreateInstance(String itemName)
   at NLog.Layouts.LayoutParser.GetLayoutRenderer(ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory, String name, Nullable`1 throwConfigExceptions)
```

Comment: You're config says `${result-payload}` ;)

Comment: @Julian Yes, sorry. It was a typo in the question. I updated the question

Comment: I think should double-check your code. `typeof(InputDataLayout)))` is not correct, is called ResultLayoutRenderer. I think this is also the issue, the mix-up of names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are very close. `NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(...)` is soon obsolete, instead it is recommended to use the [fluent configuration api](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-Configuration-API):

```
var logger = NLog.LogFactory.Setup()
    .SetupExtensions(ext =>
          ext.RegisterLayoutRenderer<ResultLayoutRenderer>("result-payload")
    )
    .LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings()
    .GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/blob/master/examples/ASP.NET%20Core%205/ASP.NET%20Core%205%20NLog%20Example/Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

This works in my ASP.NET Core 5 Web API:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LayoutRenderer.Register<ElapsedTimeLayoutRenderer>("elapsed-time");
    var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
    
    // ...
}
```

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-5
https://www.carlosjanderson.com/log-the-elapsed-time-between-log-entries-using-nlog/